# Issue with Bootstrap grid in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Rails newbie here. I am trying to to get a Bootstrap Grid to work correctly in Rails. I want a 3 column responsive grid. See below for example of 1 column:

```
<div class="box col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <h2>Content</h2>
</div>
```

I am unable to get the div columns to render beside each other, they just stack. Using the html and css outside of rails I am able to get the grid to work as expected.

I am using the following gems:

- gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
- gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2'
- gem 'bootswatch-rails' (I have also tried to do this without bootswatch)
- gem 'sass-rails'

I have been trying to fix this for a week and need a hand.

Here is my application.css.scss (I have removed all custom styling, so this is it):

```
@import "bootswatch/united/variables";
@import "bootstrap";

// Bootstrap body padding for fixed navbar
body { padding-top: 60px; }

// Responsive styles go here in case you want them
@import "bootstrap-responsive";

// And finally bootswatch style itself
@import "bootswatch/united/bootswatch";
```

I am using the following as my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                       "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
     <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here is my _header.html erb partial:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "Sweet Potato", '#', id: 'logo' %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home",    '#' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here is my home page with the grid:

```
<div class='hero-unit'>
    <h1>Sweet Potato</h1>
    <h2>Connect, Engage, Reflect</h2>
    <h3>
      Get the most out of your retreats.
    </h3>
</div>

<div class="stuff">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="box col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                 <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Connect</h3>
                     <p>Connect with the community of meditators</p>
                     <p><%= link_to "Sign up", '#',
                              class: "btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" %></p> 
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Engage</h3>
                <p>Engage in retreats</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block"       role="button">Find a Retreat</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
             <div class="thumbnail">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Organize</h3>
                <p>Organize a retreat</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" role="button">Start a Retreat</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lastly here is my _footer.html.erb

```
<footer class="footer">
  <small>
    Sweet Potato
    is made by <a href="http://www.mcgiver.io/">McGiver.io</a>
  </small>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "About",   about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 
</footer>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 classes in Bootstrap 2 by any chance?

Comment: That was it! Merry Christmas!!!!