# Can't get Bootstrap grid to work in a Rails application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My issue is very similar to [Issue with Bootstrap grid in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776400/issue-with-bootstrap-grid-in-rails) (among other similar questions I've found), except the given solution doesn't work for me. As far as I can tell, I am using Bootstrap 3 classes with the Bootstrap 3 gem, so I don't know why it still won't work.

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

In custom.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TEi-LS Data Tracker</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">6</div>
</div>
```

It outputs stacked up, no grid at all:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

This is my first question, so I hope I've given enough information. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Seems like the css is probably just not getting included.  Can you confirm by inspecting the style of the .container div from your browser.  You should see a width and a number of margin and padding properties being applied by bootstrap.

Comment: In the application.css.scss do you have //= require_tree .?

Comment: Wazery, yes, that line is present in application.css.scss. steakchaser, great suggestion, and it's led me to discover more information. I opened the page source in my browser, and looked into custom.css. The bootstrap code is there, but it's still referencing Bootstrap 2 classes (e.g. span1, span2) instead of Bootstrap 3. What could have gone wrong there? Why would @import Bootstrap find version 2, when I'm sure I installed version 3 in my Gemfile?

Comment: Okay, using information from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902488/uninstall-old-ruby-gems-versions I discovered that I had Bootstrap gems versions 2 and 3 installed locally. I don't know why Rails was ignoring my version declaration in Gemfile, but I removed the version 2 gem altogether, and now things are working as expected. Thank you! As I am still new to stackoverflow, what do I do now? Do I have to close this question somehow, or give credit to those who helped me find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your home.html.erb, you need to have a container.

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget in your custom.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Don't forget in your application.css:

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

Bootstrap uses javascript. I had a navbar class that didn't work because i didn't add the the sprocket js. Don't forget in your application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: To my understanding, by importing `bootstrap` i am importing everything. Found such info here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317357/compass-css-framework-using-bootstrap-with-sass 

Still am not able to have grid working :/