# Compass CSS framework - using Bootstrap with SASS

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass

I want to use Bootstrap with SASS, but I can't find any tutorials or explanation how one can use Bootstrap with SASS. The only thing I find is installatio trough a ruby gem:

compass create my-new-project -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap

Which creates the following tree in my folder:

[image]

Is this enough for Bootstrap to use its own Grid, because I don't see the bootstrap.scss file, neither any Grid related files. However, I find the grid classes and all in a styles.css file. Isn't there a bootstrap.scss file that has all the mixins and everything else? And where can I find a more extended use of SASS's Bootstrap mixins, which are described here briefly:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/bootstrap-and-sass/

Thank You all in advance! I really can't find nothing on my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I'm using `.sass` files in my answer, but it should apply to `.scss` files, too)*

> Isn't there a bootstrap.scss file that has all the mixins and everything else?

Yes, there is. Here's the generated [`styles.sass`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/templates/project/styles.sass) file:

```sass
// Import Bootstrap Compass integration
@import "bootstrap-compass"
// Import custom Bootstrap variables
@import "bootstrap-variables"
// Import Bootstrap for Sass
@import "bootstrap"
```

`bootstap_variables` refers to the generated [`_bootstrap-variables.sass`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/templates/project/_bootstrap-variables.sass) file in your project tree, whereas `bootstrap-compass` and `bootstrap` are imported from the gem's [stylesheets](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets/stylesheets) directory.

[The latter](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss) imports all other Bootstrap files, including the grid:

```sass
// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "bootstrap/normalize";
@import "bootstrap/print";
@import "bootstrap/glyphicons";

// Core CSS
@import "bootstrap/scaffolding";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/code";
@import "bootstrap/grid";        # <-- here it is
...
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't have the _bootsrap.scss file, which includes the Core variables,resets and core css that you listed above. Do I have to manually create it?

Comment: I downloaded the zipped assets from bootstraps website. They seem to include the missing files that compass does not create. So the way to do this is to create a compass project with bootstrap properties and then include the other files from the original Assets from the Bootstrap port?

Comment: @user3466235 the files comes with the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) gem and the gem is required from within `config.rb`. Do you get any error messages because of missing files?

Comment: No, but all of the bootstrap content that I mentioned above is missing when I simply create the project with CMD line. I added the _bootstrap.scss and the other files manually

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. The bootstrap-sass gem is a library containing all files from Bootstrap so you *don't* have to include them manually in every single project. You simply `require "bootstrap-sass"` and `@import "bootstrap"`, that's all.

Comment: So, You mean that, even if the _bootstrap.scss file and the other files are not present in my folder, Ruby includes them while compiling the sass into css?