# Bootstrap based theme with compass

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, compass

I have created a compass project with the following command:

```
compass create countdowns.io -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap --css-dir static/css --javascripts-dir static/jss --images-dir static/images --fonts-dir static/fonts
```

If i try to use grid it does not work (`.offset-md-4` is being ignored), while if i try to use, for example, buttons styles, it perfectly works. This might make me exclude that styles are not being loaded.

[image]

The html code is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">.col-md-4 .offset-md-4</div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Log me in</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course `styles.css` is loaded correctly, and the `styles.scss` content is:

```
// Import Bootstrap Compass integration
@import "bootstrap-compass";

// Import custom Bootstrap variables
@import "bootstrap-variables";

// Import Bootstrap for Sass
@import "bootstrap";


div {
    outline: 1px red solid;
}
```

Comment: I think you also need to load `bootstrap-grid` and/or similar components to get specific bits to work? Its been a while since I worked with it but I remember a bunch of imports being specified.

Comment: @somethinghere To my knowledge, by importing `bootstrap` i have imported everything. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317357/compass-css-framework-using-bootstrap-with-sass/28318224#28318224